# Kusto Query- i need past 7 days off each day count and past 30days of each day count of Unauthorized messages in single output result format

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql

I need past 24 hrs and past 7 days of each day count and past 30 days of each day count which is having azure in message column.

Past 24hrs query:

```
| where message has "azure" 
| where timestamp  > ago(24h)   
| summarize count() by message = "azure"
```

Past 7days of each day count query:

```
| where message has "azure"
| where timestamp >= startofday(ago(7d))
| where timestamp  < startofday(now())
| summarize count() by startofday(timestamp) , message ="azure"
```

Past 30days of  each day count query:

```
| where message has "azure"
| where timestamp >= 'startofday'(ago(30d))`enter code here`
| where timestamp  < `startofday'(now())
| summarize count() by startofday(timestamp) ,  message = "azure"
```

Can we combine these 3 queries and make output result as single?
Sample data:

| Timestamp | message |
| --- | --- |
| 2009-09-17 12:45:37 | Azure |
| 2009-09-18 12:45:39 | Aws |
| 2009-09-29 13:29:12 | Google |
| 2009-09-12 13:29:14 | Aws |
| 2009-09-19 13:29:17 | Azure |
| 2009-09-14 13:29:23 | Google |

Expected output:

| Timestamp | message | count_24hrs | count_7days | count_30days |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2009-09-16 12:45:37 | Azure | 152 | 152 | 152 |
| 2009-09-15 12:45:39 | Azure |  | 65 | 65 |
| 2009-09-14 13:29:12 | Azure |  | 6587 | 6587 |
| 2009-09-13 13:29:14 | Azure |  | 98 | 98 |
| 2009-09-12 13:29:17 | Azure |  | 54365 | 54365 |
| 2009-09-11 13:29:23 | Azure |  | 12 | 12 |
|  |  |  | 97 | 97 |
|  |  |  |  | 987 |
|  |  |  |  | 98 |

... Up to past 30days

Comment: The result's timestamps don't make sense

Comment: Means past 24hrs and past 7days and past 30days timestamp query is not possible in KQL

Comment: Please don't destroy the formatting

Comment: Thank you @DavidדודוMarkovitz , this was indeed the solution!

Comment: Great. In that case make sure to accept the solution (mark the V symbol near the answer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you are looking for something like this, although this is definitely not the way I would have chosen to display this data.

```
// Data sample generation. Not part of the solution.
let t = materialize(range i from 1 to 1000 step 1 | extend timestamp = ago(35d*rand()), message = tostring(dynamic(["Azure", "AWS", "GCP"])[toint(rand(3))])); 
// Solution starts here
t
| where timestamp >= startofday(ago(30d))
| summarize count_24h   = countif(timestamp >= ago(24h))
           ,count_7d    = countif(timestamp >= startofday(ago(7d)) and timestamp < startofday(now()))
           ,count_30d   = countif(timestamp < startofday(now()))
            by message, startofday(timestamp)
| order by message, timestamp
```

| message | timestamp | count_24h | count_7d | count_30d |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| GCP | 2022-09-15T00:00:00Z | 6 | 0 | 0 |
| GCP | 2022-09-14T00:00:00Z | 1 | 9 | 9 |
| GCP | 2022-09-13T00:00:00Z | 0 | 12 | 12 |
| GCP | 2022-09-12T00:00:00Z | 0 | 7 | 7 |
| GCP | 2022-09-11T00:00:00Z | 0 | 7 | 7 |
| GCP | 2022-09-10T00:00:00Z | 0 | 11 | 11 |
| GCP | 2022-09-09T00:00:00Z | 0 | 14 | 14 |
| GCP | 2022-09-08T00:00:00Z | 0 | 10 | 10 |
| GCP | 2022-09-07T00:00:00Z | 0 | 0 | 9 |
| GCP | 2022-09-06T00:00:00Z | 0 | 0 | 12 |
| GCP | 2022-09-05T00:00:00Z | 0 | 0 | 12 |
| GCP | 2022-09-04T00:00:00Z | 0 | 0 | 6 |
| GCP | 2022-09-03T00:00:00Z | 0 | 0 | 9 |
| GCP | 2022-09-02T00:00:00Z | 0 | 0 | 12 |
| GCP | 2022-09-01T00:00:00Z | 0 | 0 | 6 |
| GCP | 2022-08-31T00:00:00Z | 0 | 0 | 12 |
| GCP | 2022-08-30T00:00:00Z | 0 | 0 | 12 |
| GCP | 2022-08-29T00:00:00Z | 0 | 0 | 12 |
| GCP | 2022-08-28T00:00:00Z | 0 | 0 | 5 |
| GCP | 2022-08-27T00:00:00Z | 0 | 0 | 8 |
| GCP | 2022-08-26T00:00:00Z | 0 | 0 | 10 |
| GCP | 2022-08-25T00:00:00Z | 0 | 0 | 15 |
| GCP | 2022-08-24T00:00:00Z | 0 | 0 | 11 |
| GCP | 2022-08-23T00:00:00Z | 0 | 0 | 9 |
| GCP | 2022-08-22T00:00:00Z | 0 | 0 | 12 |
| GCP | 2022-08-21T00:00:00Z | 0 | 0 | 10 |
| GCP | 2022-08-20T00:00:00Z | 0 | 0 | 11 |
| GCP | 2022-08-19T00:00:00Z | 0 | 0 | 6 |
| GCP | 2022-08-18T00:00:00Z | 0 | 0 | 10 |
| GCP | 2022-08-17T00:00:00Z | 0 | 0 | 8 |
| GCP | 2022-08-16T00:00:00Z | 0 | 0 | 6 |
| Azure | 2022-09-15T00:00:00Z | 7 | 0 | 0 |
| Azure | 2022-09-14T00:00:00Z | 1 | 6 | 6 |
| Azure | 2022-09-13T00:00:00Z | 0 | 14 | 14 |
| Azure | 2022-09-12T00:00:00Z | 0 | 10 | 10 |
| Azure | 2022-09-11T00:00:00Z | 0 | 13 | 13 |
| Azure | 2022-09-10T00:00:00Z | 0 | 7 | 7 |
| Azure | 2022-09-09T00:00:00Z | 0 | 12 | 12 |
| Azure | 2022-09-08T00:00:00Z | 0 | 5 | 5 |
| Azure | 2022-09-07T00:00:00Z | 0 | 0 | 10 |
| Azure | 2022-09-06T00:00:00Z | 0 | 0 | 10 |
| Azure | 2022-09-05T00:00:00Z | 0 | 0 | 5 |
| Azure | 2022-09-04T00:00:00Z | 0 | 0 | 11 |
| Azure | 2022-09-03T00:00:00Z | 0 | 0 | 7 |
| Azure | 2022-09-02T00:00:00Z | 0 | 0 | 8 |
| Azure | 2022-09-01T00:00:00Z | 0 | 0 | 10 |
| Azure | 2022-08-31T00:00:00Z | 0 | 0 | 8 |
| Azure | 2022-08-30T00:00:00Z | 0 | 0 | 10 |
| Azure | 2022-08-29T00:00:00Z | 0 | 0 | 13 |
| Azure | 2022-08-28T00:00:00Z | 0 | 0 | 14 |
| Azure | 2022-08-27T00:00:00Z | 0 | 0 | 9 |
| Azure | 2022-08-26T00:00:00Z | 0 | 0 | 8 |
| Azure | 2022-08-25T00:00:00Z | 0 | 0 | 3 |
| Azure | 2022-08-24T00:00:00Z | 0 | 0 | 8 |
| Azure | 2022-08-23T00:00:00Z | 0 | 0 | 10 |
| Azure | 2022-08-22T00:00:00Z | 0 | 0 | 8 |
| Azure | 2022-08-21T00:00:00Z | 0 | 0 | 17 |
| Azure | 2022-08-20T00:00:00Z | 0 | 0 | 7 |
| Azure | 2022-08-19T00:00:00Z | 0 | 0 | 11 |
| Azure | 2022-08-18T00:00:00Z | 0 | 0 | 9 |
| Azure | 2022-08-17T00:00:00Z | 0 | 0 | 7 |
| Azure | 2022-08-16T00:00:00Z | 0 | 0 | 8 |
| AWS | 2022-09-15T00:00:00Z | 3 | 0 | 0 |
| AWS | 2022-09-14T00:00:00Z | 2 | 4 | 4 |
| AWS | 2022-09-13T00:00:00Z | 0 | 11 | 11 |
| AWS | 2022-09-12T00:00:00Z | 0 | 8 | 8 |
| AWS | 2022-09-11T00:00:00Z | 0 | 8 | 8 |
| AWS | 2022-09-10T00:00:00Z | 0 | 10 | 10 |
| AWS | 2022-09-09T00:00:00Z | 0 | 13 | 13 |
| AWS | 2022-09-08T00:00:00Z | 0 | 7 | 7 |
| AWS | 2022-09-07T00:00:00Z | 0 | 0 | 11 |
| AWS | 2022-09-06T00:00:00Z | 0 | 0 | 12 |
| AWS | 2022-09-05T00:00:00Z | 0 | 0 | 7 |
| AWS | 2022-09-04T00:00:00Z | 0 | 0 | 10 |
| AWS | 2022-09-03T00:00:00Z | 0 | 0 | 8 |
| AWS | 2022-09-02T00:00:00Z | 0 | 0 | 13 |
| AWS | 2022-09-01T00:00:00Z | 0 | 0 | 5 |
| AWS | 2022-08-31T00:00:00Z | 0 | 0 | 11 |
| AWS | 2022-08-30T00:00:00Z | 0 | 0 | 9 |
| AWS | 2022-08-29T00:00:00Z | 0 | 0 | 9 |
| AWS | 2022-08-28T00:00:00Z | 0 | 0 | 14 |
| AWS | 2022-08-27T00:00:00Z | 0 | 0 | 14 |
| AWS | 2022-08-26T00:00:00Z | 0 | 0 | 8 |
| AWS | 2022-08-25T00:00:00Z | 0 | 0 | 15 |
| AWS | 2022-08-24T00:00:00Z | 0 | 0 | 9 |
| AWS | 2022-08-23T00:00:00Z | 0 | 0 | 7 |
| AWS | 2022-08-22T00:00:00Z | 0 | 0 | 9 |
| AWS | 2022-08-21T00:00:00Z | 0 | 0 | 11 |
| AWS | 2022-08-20T00:00:00Z | 0 | 0 | 6 |
| AWS | 2022-08-19T00:00:00Z | 0 | 0 | 12 |
| AWS | 2022-08-18T00:00:00Z | 0 | 0 | 12 |
| AWS | 2022-08-17T00:00:00Z | 0 | 0 | 9 |
| AWS | 2022-08-16T00:00:00Z | 0 | 0 | 5 |

[Fiddle](https://dataexplorer.azure.com/clusters/help/databases/Samples?query=H4sIAAAAAAAAA4VRz0vDMBS+F/o/fPTUSLGdU3bQCUPBmwg7eBhD4vLaBdpkJK/Mjf3xpp3OTRzmkjze9+u95DkeJUt42axqQkWGnGRtzSWeLWMlHcOW4CXB27rtO3FUE4MxRiOZnJa13lLqpKkIGqWzDQZgi0FRFPBMq1DuQB9MRoF1Q56DW6DLyqbDG3URqCoVIkNoeRlUxoHu2WlTpWpjZKMX6SyZbFtHSYZk8jrtrqeHl2QuZmy14bSXGAoxF+IWcZTnmH7FDQnCEB5LchRHHEc7rLv3UZL78R5kSyU3aZ+qUEJ0UN82jXRhPixsa/jt6noJhHx9pcv0RKRjBkDHxM/J9syRwnnmL/tRcIc82dbdMcbYddjXnzYh+RmbfxXwvvn+gewYe5DoN2KdIncCPfQ/AQd9TCFNAgAA)

Comment: See updated answer (fixed the last 24h, according to your query)